# Drawing more than one rectangle on canvas as user moves finger on screen

Tags: android

I used the below code to draw rectangle on canvas as user touches the screen, where the first coordinates are where user first touches screen, it worked.

problem: I am able to draw only one rectangle , when I want to draw a second one the first one disappears (I want to draw as many as I want).

second problem : how to draw triangle and circle using same method?

the code:

```
//In a custom view class
int mStartX;
int mStartY;
int mEndX;
int mEndY;

Paint paint = new Paint();

//I did constructor and everything.........

//Drawing the rectangle in on draw
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

super.onDraw(canvas);

canvas.drawRect(mStartX, mStartY, mEndX, mEndY, paint);
}


//updating the coordinate variables on touch

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

switch (event.getActionMasked()) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        mStartX = (int) event.getX();
        mStartY = (int) event.getY();

        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        mEndX = (int) event.getX();
        mEndY = (int) event.getY();

        invalidate();

        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:


        mEndX = (int) event.getX();
        mEndY = (int) event.getY();

        invalidate();

        break;

    default:

        return false;

        break;
}

return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> when I want to draw a second one the first one disappears

just because you invoke invalidate() command.

You can create some draw (sprite) object and store coordinates for draw into itself and then draw this objects collection when onDraw(Canvas canvas) invokes after invalidate().

> second problem : how to draw triangle and circle using same method?

read [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) to find required commands